# Check if Document name exists in firebase database collection

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want users to Login to my app via Document name/id. When they enter and click login i want to Search if the document name exists in collection or not. The following code is force closing app on submit!

Please check what wrong am I doing and please post fixed code if possible.

```
package net.smallacademy.authenticatorapp;
import...

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText mKey;
Button mLoginBtn;
ProgressBar progressBar;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    mKey = findViewById(R.id.key);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String key = mKey.getText().toString().trim();


            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(key)){
                mKey.setError("Key is Required.");
                return;
            }
            if(key.length() < 6){
                mKey.setError("Key Must be >= 6 Characters");
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("members").document(String.valueOf (mKey));
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot snap, FirebaseFirestoreException fe) {
                    if (snap.exists ( )) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }



                });

        }

    });

    }





}
```

LOGCAT:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there was a crash, check the logcat output of your app for the exact error message and stack trace and add those to your question.

Comment: Please add it to your question what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I am getting error when adding logcat to question so I have added screenshots.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I have also uploaded logcat at: https://pastebin.com/raw/cGUhxcZv

Comment: @ChMoazzam What does `String.valueOf (mKey)` return?

Comment: On app start screen there is a text input field and a Login button. mKey is the value of input field, and clicking login I want to check whether mKey matches any document name in firebase collection on not. There could be an error in code because i am a beginner

Comment: @ChMoazzam - were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: could you share an example of the input on that field? as by the error message this might be because of a "/" in the input or the reading method also if you could log `String.valueOf (mKey)` can be helpful